# Retail vs institutional percentage estimation in equity futures market (CME)

Tags: futures, statistics, cme

I am trying to find the most/least "popular with retail futures traders" instrument based on public data. I managed to estimate retail/institutional proportions by aggregating OI data from COT reports.

But I am not confident that OI percentage reflects real situtation. I would prefer to know how long on the average each groups holds their positions (and maybe weighted by vlm).

Are there any sources to do that? (Or if you know better way to estimate proportions, I'd appreciate your advice)

Comment: What does "populated" mean to you in this respect? Could you please clarify? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: @Kermittfrog I meant some equity which is traded by retail more than other equities (in relative values). My goal is to form a sorted list of equities futures and then adjust my trading strategy